# Accessing an object property in the same object

Tags: javascript

I have an object `cats` like this:

```
var model = {
    cats: [
        {
            name: "Fossie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Bootsie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        }
    ], 
    currentCat: cats[0], //error here
}
```

When I try to access `cats[0]`, I get following error: `ReferenceError: cats is not defined`

If I replace `cats[0]` with `this.cats[0]` I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Is it not possible to access an object's property within the same object? Or should I create a function inside `model` and initialize `currentCat` in there?

Comment: It is not possible to reference an object from inside its object initializer expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Try this instead:

```
var model = {
    cats: [
        {
            name: "Fossie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Bootsie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        }
    ]
}
model.currentCat = model.cats[0];
```

You can't use the object before it has been initialised - so, where you were trying to set `currentCat`, you were still 'inside' the intialisation, and your model was not accessible.

After this code, model will look like:

```
model = {
    cats: [
        {
            name: "Fossie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Bootsie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        }
    ],
    currentCat: {
        name: "Fossie",
        url: "",
        count: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer. So I understand the reason it's not working. `cats` is not yet initialized when I do `cats[0]` within model. Right? Also, as per your answer, `model.currentCat = model.cats[0];` will assign `currentcat` property to `model` object and then assign it to first cat, right?

Comment: First part is correct. `model.currentCat = model.cats[0];` will set the value of `model.currentCat` to whatever the value is of the first element in your array `model.cats`. The model itself won't be stored.

Comment: Is there any way I can contain `currentCat` inside `model`? Just to make it more readable? Thanks

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have been more clear - this will indeed contain it inside `model`
I'll update my post with an example of what `model` will look like after the code has run

Comment: Perfect. I wanted to access `currentCat` as `model.currentCat` from my controller, which I believe this will do. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! If the answer is correct, please mark it as such so that future users know to use it! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could store the current cat's index instead (and access the property in a function using `this`):

```
var model = {
    cats: [
        {
            name: "Fossie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Bootsie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        }
    ], 
    currentCatIndex: 0,
    getCurrentCat: function() {
        return this.cats[this.currentCatIndex];
    }
}
console.log(model.getCurrentCat());
```

Comment: I like this approach as well. Thank you @falsarella.

Answer (score -1):

Dont use it inside the model. Use it after the cats is defined.

```
var model = {
    cats: [
        {
            name: "Fossie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        },
        {
            name: "Bootsie",
            url: "",
            count: 0
        }
    ], 
    // currentCat: cats[0], //error here
}
model.currentCat = model.cats[0];
```

Hopefully this will be good for you